# How to get md5(unicode) hash of a string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, md5, hashlib

I want use python to generate hash of the md5(unicode) type.
Such as I query in www.cmd5.org/hash.aspx

Different types od md5 hash

[image]

But in Python, using ***hashlib***,I got hash of md5 type and can't generate hash of the md5(unicode) type.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.md5("1".encode('utf-8'))
>>> m.hexdigest()
'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'
```

How can I get that? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: not sure your question, shall it be: m.digest() ?